# Having troubles with cx_freeze

Tags: python, cx-freeze

Having a trouble with installing dev version of cxFreeze. That's what I am trying to do.

```
pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze.git@master
```

And I am getting that scary stuff:

```
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\администратор\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include -Ic:\users\администратор\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsource/bases/Console.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\source/bases/Console.obj
    Console.c
    creating C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Temp\3\pip-req-build-dkpb78tf\build\lib.win32-3.8\cx_Freeze\bases
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=1 /LIBPATH:c:\users\администратор\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\администратор\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\PCbuild\win32 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\lib\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86" imagehlp.lib Shlwapi.lib build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\source/bases/Console.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-3.8\cx_Freeze\bases\Console.exe /MANIFEST
    ‘®§¤ ­ЁҐ Є®¤
    ‘®§¤ ­ЁҐ Є®¤  § ўҐаиҐ­®
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\администратор\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include -Ic:\users\администратор\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsource/bases/Win32GUI.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\source/bases/Win32GUI.obj
    Win32GUI.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=1 /LIBPATH:c:\users\администратор\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\администратор\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\PCbuild\win32 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\lib\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86" imagehlp.lib Shlwapi.lib user32.lib build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\source/bases/Win32GUI.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-3.8\cx_Freeze\bases\Win32GUI.exe /MANIFEST
    ‘®§¤ ­ЁҐ Є®¤
    ‘®§¤ ­ЁҐ Є®¤  § ўҐаиҐ­®
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Temp\3\cx_Logging\src -Ic:\users\администратор\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include -Ic:\users\администратор\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsource/bases/Win32Service.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\source/bases/Win32Service.obj
    Win32Service.c
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=1 /LIBPATH:C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Temp\3\cx_Logging\build\implib.win32-3.8 /LIBPATH:c:\users\администратор\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\администратор\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\PCbuild\win32 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\lib\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.18362.0\um\x86" imagehlp.lib Shlwapi.lib advapi32.lib cx_Logging.lib build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\source/bases/Win32Service.obj /OUT:build\lib.win32-3.8\cx_Freeze\bases\Win32Service.exe /MANIFEST
    LINK : fatal error LNK1181: ­Ґ г¤ Ґвбп ®вЄалвм ўе®¤­®© д ©« "cx_Logging.lib"
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.27.29110\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1181
    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of cx-freeze
  Moving to c:\users\администратор\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\cx_freeze-6.2.dist-info\
   from C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\~x_freeze-6.2.dist-info
  Moving to c:\users\администратор\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\cx_freeze\
   from C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\~x_freeze
  Moving to c:\users\администратор\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\scripts\cxfreeze-quickstart.exe
   from C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Temp\3\pip-uninstall-c94uri98\cxfreeze-quickstart.exe
  Moving to c:\users\администратор\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\scripts\cxfreeze.exe
   from C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Temp\3\pip-uninstall-c94uri98\cxfreeze.exe
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\администратор\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Администратор\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\3\\pip-req-build-dkpb78tf\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Администратор\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\3\\pip-req-build-dkpb78tf\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Администратор\AppData\Local\Temp\3\pip-record-32d5ppl7\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\администратор\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\cx-Freeze' Check the logs for full command output.
```

What should I do? I am using Python 3.8, so I need new version of cxFreeze, cuz 6.2 is not really working for me...